# .velocity("scroll") does not work properly if used inside a $window.scroll() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Lately, I have been working on a website where I want to shoot specific effects at different scroll positions. I am using Velocity JS for the animation.There is an element where I want to have an automatic scroll to another specific scroll position. This can be easily achieved using Velocity JS. Below is the piece of code which illustrates the case:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window.scrollTop() > 100)
  {$('#element').velocity('scroll',{duration: 1000, offset:500});}
});
```

So now when the scroll position is more than 100 the element will be automatically scrolled to an offset of 500.Now the problem here is that once the animation is executed the scroll gets stuck and gets unstable. So the question is, How to get rid of this issue ? Why is this happening ? Is there an alternate way to achieve what I want?  Here is a Fiddle that elaborates the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/zubairanwar2/65xCP/58/

I am fairly new in using velocity Js so please advice me and help me. Thank you !

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `velocity` plugin, it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do. You're telling it to scroll to `500` if the scrollTop is greater than `100`. So when you're at `500`, because `500` is greater than `100`, the `velocity` function is fired instantly on any scroll event. Perhaps you should check scroll direction, and only fire the `velocity` function if the user is scrolling down, and within a certain range, eg `> 100 && < 120`.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I found the solution from jQuery itself. Instead of just calling the function like this :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 100 && $(window).scrollTop() < 500) // > 100 AND    < 500
 {$('#element').velocity('scroll',{duration: 1000, offset:500});}
});
```

We can use , `$(document).one('scroll',function(){});`. What it does is it will run the function atmost once. So the above code can be re-written as:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) 
 {  
    $(document).one('scroll',function(){
         $('#element').velocity('scroll',{duration: 1000, offset:500});
   });

  }
});
```

And thats the solution so far I got and it works like a charm. Please comment if there is anything wrong with this code or if you want to add something more. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have, with my comments to help you understand what is happening (if you don't already):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ //when you scroll...
   if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) //if you are > 100 px from the top of the page...
  {$('#element').velocity('scroll',{duration: 1000, offset:500});} // scroll to 500
});
```

When you are scrolled to 500 px, you are more than 100px from the top, right? So every time you scroll, it is scrolling you back to 500.

Here is the solution to your problem: Just change the if statement so that velocity only fires when you actually want it to:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() > 100 && $(window).scrollTop() < 500) // > 100 AND < 500
  {$('#element').velocity('scroll',{duration: 1000, offset:500});}
});
```

If you want to be able to scroll back up from 500, then change it to something smaller, but still larger than 100, such as 120.

P.S There is a syntax error in your code, but as you said that it is partly working I assume it is a typo.. but here it is anyway: `$(window.scrollTop()` is missing a closing bracket around `window`; i.e `$(window).scrollTop()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, even if I dont keep any condition still the scroll gets stuck as long as it is inside the $(window).scroll(function(){}); Thats the issue here. Its quite strange actually here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zubairanwar2/65xCP/61/

Comment: that's not strange, it's the expected behavior.. you are binding the function to the scroll event so if you don't stop it from happening by specifying the conditions then it will fire every time  you scroll. Add `console.log($(window).scrollTop());` inside the `.scroll(function());` and you will see what I mean

Comment: I have tried some conditions yet it is futile. You are correct that as long the function is called in `.scroll(function(){})` this problem will persist as the function is called multiple times. Any thoughts on how to overcome this issue ?

Comment: I thought of a solution, what do you think if I use jquery.off() in the conditions where I want to fire the velocity animation. Whats your thought about it ?